# Geometry puzzle

Tags: mathematics, geometry

[image: Triangle with sides x,y,z. Three equal length line segments parallel to the sides intersect at point W and are bounded by the triangle.]

The lengths of the triangle sides satisfy $x < y < z$. Lines that look parallel indeed are parallel. Triangles that look similar indeed are similar. The three red lines are concurrent (meet at a single point) and congruent (have the same length). What is their length?

Comment: Do you want their length in terms of x, y, and z?

Comment: Yeah, a general solution in terms of x, y, and z. I saw this puzzle posed specifically for a 3:4:6 triangle, and hammered away at it for a while before going to bed.

Comment: Nice solutions... So the answer to the 3:4:6 triangle is 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Let $a$ be the proportion of the dimensions of the triangle including the line from $y$ to $z$ to those of the full triangle. Define $b$ and $c$ similarly for the lines from $x$ to $z$, and from $x$ to $y$. Then, from similarity, $ax=by=cz$. 
>  Also, if we look at side $x$, we can see from similarity that the section from the bottom to the $xz$ line has length $bx$, the section from the top to the $xy$ line has length $cx$, and the overlap of those two sections (the section between the two red lines) has length $(1-a)x$. Thus 
>  $bx + cx - (1-a)x = x$ 
>  $\implies a+b+c=2$ 
> Substituting $b=\frac{ax}{y}$ and $c=\frac{ax}{z}$, we have 
> $a+\frac{ax}{y}+\frac{ax}{z}=2$ 
> $\implies a(\frac{yz+xz+xy}{yz})=2$ 
>  $\implies ax=\frac{2xyz}{xy+yz+zx}$
> Since the three lines are congruent, this is the length of all of them.

Comment: Duuude...spoilers? :)

Answer (score 2):

Answer

> $\frac{2*x*y*z}{x*y + x*z + y*z}$

Proof:
Let's convene to the notations on the image:

And let's make the length of the red lines $q$.

> [image]
>  
>  $AxH = AyA$
>  $BxH = BzB$
>  
>  This means $AB = AxBx + AyBz$ which translates to $AyBz = x-q$
>  
>  In a similar logic $AxCz = y-q$
>  
>  Triangle AyBzH is similar to ABC This results in
>  
>  $\frac{AyBz}{x} = \frac{BzH}{z}$
>  
>  Triangle AxCzH is similar to ABC   This results in
>  
>  $\frac{AxCz}{y} = \frac{CzH}{z}$
>  
>  Adding the 2 above and replacing $AxBz$ with $y-q$ and $AyBz$ with
>  $x-q$  we end up with
>  
>  $\frac{x-q}{x} + \frac{y-q}{y} = \frac{BzH}{z} + \frac{CzH}{z}$
>  
>  This is the same as
>  
>  $1- \frac{q}{x} + 1 - \frac{q}{y} = \frac{BzH + CzH}{z}$
>  But $BzH +CzH = q$
>  So 
>  $1- \frac{q}{x} + 1 - \frac{q}{y} = \frac{q}{z}$
>  
>  Resolving the equation for unknown $q$ we get
>  
>  $q = \frac{2*x*y*z}{x*y + x*z + y*z}$